# Find occuracy of IABcategory per userID in large dataset

Tags: r, data.table

```
IAB_category                          global_uuid timestamp_visit          domain.x     userID is_mapped          iab_name mapped_times cnt_usr_act cnt_IAB
   1:          art 0f9a4340-b64b-4920-a63c-015cb0616a73      1464813590 biznes.interia.pl a89ecee16b      true sztuka i rozrywka          332         125   37492
   2:          art 35b69ecf-709a-4235-96ed-7688d2a3b3ca      1465242957 biznes.interia.pl 5f6cc26a04      true sztuka i rozrywka          332         533   37492
   3:          art 7aa2a096-7cb1-41da-90eb-e1aeb5b034cd      1465280801 biznes.interia.pl e4b6405999      true sztuka i rozrywka          332         129   37492
   4:          art 90fcdf2b-bf19-4f55-b706-1f434a7e96bc      1465277645 biznes.interia.pl b128940b4d      true sztuka i rozrywka          332         569   37492
   5:          art 9d2eb1e5-50f7-4c2f-b353-a4ad371e3bda      1465266998 biznes.interia.pl f72c43e84c      true sztuka i rozrywka          332         286   37492
  ---                                                                                                                                                            
17587528:  tra_tra_tra 0d41317a-eda4-4ca8-aa30-7a951d1b654e      1466778469  www.promoceny.pl b5c6b21a9f      true  podróż pociągiem           15         251   38258
17587529:  tra_tra_tra 0d41317a-eda4-4ca8-aa30-7a951d1b654e      1466778477  www.promoceny.pl b5c6b21a9f      true  podróż pociągiem           15         251   38258
17587530:  tra_tra_tra a7276c02-6602-4849-849c-376c6a8b3d76      1465070638 www.rmfclassic.pl 5449d119bf      true  podróż pociągiem           15         368   38258
17587531:  tra_tra_tra 00c5a0a8-db0d-4283-8283-a038cbcfca47      1467114032  fakty.interia.pl 9e7ba73702      true  podróż pociągiem           15         628   38258
17587532:  tra_tra_tra 5f0ba278-7ec3-4ab4-affa-51133c7081d7      1466601726  fakty.interia.pl cfc4aadc43      true  podróż pociągiem           15         271   38258
```

I have the above data. It's around 17 millions of rows. I am able to identifyactive users (when user have more that 100 rows). I am doing it in following way:

```
total <- total[, cnt_usr_act:=.N, by=userID][cnt_usr_act >= 100]
```

However I want to find for each userID what is his IAB_category and check the most popular. I can easily do this for all users in following way:

```
total <- total[, cnt_IAB:=.N, by=IAB_category][cnt_IAB >= 50]
```

but it's still not per userID, it's for all users.

Comment: How about grouping by user and category, computing the number of rows and then grouping only by user to extract rows with the maximum number of rows computed in first step?

Comment: Thank you for comment. I know hot to group by particular user, but I have more that 100 000 users. I don't know how to write a function which take user x and will check IAB.

Comment: Just use `total[, cnt_usr_act_cat :=.N, by = list(userID, IAB_category)]` and then select the maximum of that new column with `by = userID`